# Is spark-snowflake connector is only available for databricks spark?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using databricks spark, able to write the data into snowflake using **spark-snowflake connector**(spark-snowflake_2.11-2.3.0.jar, snowflake-jdbc-2.8.1.jar), not using JDBC connection. But without databricks when i try to apply the same code in local machine where spark is installed, I am not able to write into snowflake using spark-snowflake connector. The **error** i face is **classNotFoundExceptoion for snowflake.DefaultSource**.
But able to write to snowflake using JDBC connection from local machine where spark is installed locally.

Answer (score 3):

the `spark-snowflake` package is not included in spark. you should include it when running spark with:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.5
```

or add it to your dependencies like this (in sbt):

```
libraryDependencies += "net.snowflake" %% "spark-snowflake" % "2.4.5"
```

see here for details: https://spark-packages.org/package/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax for adding this as a sbt dependency is:

libraryDependencies += "net.snowflake" % "spark-snowflake_2.11" % "2.9.0-spark_2.4"

Reference: https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.snowflake/spark-snowflake_2.11/2.9.0-spark_2.4/jar

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.